# How can I scrap website that use Request Verification Token in request?

Tags: scala, web-scraping, akka-http

I'm trying to scrap website, but the problem is it requires Request Verification Token in the request.

For this I try to get Request Verification Token from home page of the website - then try to scrap website with that Request Verification Token in the request. I'm using Scala Version 2.13.1, sbt version 1.2.8 and libraries  ("org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.15.3",
"net.ruippeixotog" %% "scala-scraper" % "3.0.0").

**With Akka HTTP Client**

```
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  // Define the URL you want to scrape
  val url = "https://solutions.virginia.gov/Notary/Search/Search"

  // Make a GET request to the URL
  val requestForToken = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, url)
  val responseFutureForToken = Http().singleRequest(requestForToken)

  // Extract the RequestVerificationToken from the response headers
  val tokenFuture = responseFutureForToken.map { response =>
    val tokenHeaders = response.headers.toList
    val setCookieRequestVerificationToken = tokenHeaders(6).toString().split("\\s+|;|=").toList
    setCookieRequestVerificationToken(2)
  }

  // Wait for the token value and print it
  val requestVerificationToken = Await.result(tokenFuture, 5.seconds)
  println(requestVerificationToken)

  val postBody = s"__RequestVerificationToken=$requestVerificationToken&Query.FirstName=ab&Query.LastName=ab&Query.NotaryId="
  val request = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, url, Nil, HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, postBody))
  val responseFuture = Http(system).singleRequest(request)

  responseFuture
    .onComplete {
      case Success(res) => logger.info("Result is: {} ", res)
        Unmarshal(res.entity.toStrict(180 seconds)).value.map { result =>
          val htmlStr = result.data.utf8String
          val browser = JsoupBrowser()
          val doc = browser.parseString(htmlStr)
          println(doc)
        }
      case Failure(e) =>
        println(ServerMessage.EXCEPTION)
    }
```

**Output**
It is giving:

```
Request Verification Code: GcgyA-aWo0c0FhTCQUwxd4ne14KPvPbiU6hBNPmbFJHACjnZOmIINyqa2EPwXq_82JbGMttj21V0NIw5yQnSDo4_SjAK-oOlcdCoyDGucSM1
18:04:31.873 521 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] LogFactory$ INFO - Result is: HttpResponse(302 Found,List(Cache-Control: private, Location: /Notary/Error/500?aspxerrorpath=/Notary/Search/Search, Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0, X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2, X-Powered-By: ASP.NET, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, Date: Fri, 26 May 2023 13:04:30 GMT),HttpEntity.Strict(text/html; charset=UTF-8,170 bytes total),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1)) 
JsoupDocument(<html>
 <head>
  <title>Object moved</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Object moved to <a href="/Notary/Error/500?aspxerrorpath=/Notary/Search/Search">here</a>.</h2>
 </body>
</html>)
```

**Without Akka HTTP Client**

```
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  // Define the URL you want to scrape
  val url = "https://solutions.virginia.gov/Notary/Search/Search"

  // Make a GET request to the URL
  val requestForToken = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, url)
  val responseFutureForToken = Http().singleRequest(requestForToken)

  // Extract the RequestVerificationToken from the response headers
  val tokenFuture = responseFutureForToken.map { response =>
    val tokenHeaders = response.headers.toList
    val setCookieRequestVerificationToken = tokenHeaders(6).toString().split("\\s+|;|=").toList
    setCookieRequestVerificationToken(2)
  }

  // Wait for the token value and print it
  val requestVerificationToken = Await.result(tokenFuture, 5.seconds)
  println("Request Verification Code: " + requestVerificationToken)

  val formData = Map(
    "__RequestVerificationToken" -> requestVerificationToken,
    "FirstName" -> "ab",
    "LastName" -> "ab",
    "NotaryId" -> "",
  )

  val browser = JsoupBrowser()
  val doc = browser.post(url, formData)
  println(doc)
```

**Output**

```
Request Verification Code: x68MuhunwLyyHNxZjjVJzqf-VAIAiCNtyfNDlBabjyIA7rO1XtURuEfYhiryMOqKnZGfR-oPP4DmzU0Ju3Ed3ULnhtBnLP9GE8tD-MxLNKU1
JsoupDocument(<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Notary, Kay Coles James, Commonwealth, Secretary of the Commonwealth, Glenn Youngkin, governor, virginia, VA">
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
  <meta name="author" content="webmaster@governor.virginia.gov">
  <title>500 - Error</title>
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.